# Why is my nlp model not running properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, lstm

I am trying to create a sentiment anaylsis model using keras:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, SpatialDropout1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding

data = pd.read_csv('./movie-reviews.csv')
data['label'].value_counts()
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['text'])
encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['text'])
padded_sequence = pad_sequences(encoded, maxlen=200)
embedding_vector_length = 32

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(20, embedding_vector_length, input_length=200))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(50, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())
history = model.fit(padded_sequence, data['label'] ,epochs=5)
```

but i am getting the below error:

```
Epoch 1/5
C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:1176: SyntaxWarning: In loss categorical_crossentropy, expected y_pred.shape to be (batch_size, num_classes) with num_classes > 1. Received: y_pred.shape=(32, 1). Consider using 'binary_crossentropy' if you only have 2 classes.
  return dispatch_target(*args, **kwargs)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 1
----> 1 history = model.fit(padded_sequence, data['label'] ,epochs=5)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential_3/embedding_3/embedding_lookup' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
    File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 992, in l
```

I tried to change the compile line but nothing works.

Comment: The error seems to come from the shape of y_pred. How many classes are you trying to predict ?

Comment: 2 classes postive and negative .

Comment: You cannot use categorical crossentropy for your loss function as it expects more than two classes. So, the first step to debug your code is to replace it with 'binary_crossentropy'. If the code still does not wirk, please update your post with the new error message.

Comment: nothing new same error

Comment: What is the new shape of y_pred ?

Comment: if i change the y_pred into 2 I am getting the above error but if I change it into 1 I got the below error .  ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((32, 2) vs (32, 1)).

Comment: What is the shape of data['label'] ?

Comment: data['label'].shape ----->  (40000,)